# Are there replacements for the reg commad on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

I believe `reg` existed on 10.8 and lower as documented here - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/reg.1.html

However, in OS X 10.9 I only find man page but not the command. My requirement is to passively monitor the processor registers (dump them). It looks like 'reg' does that.

Is there an equivalent utility that I download somewhere for MAC OS X >= 10.9.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I've edited out the trivial yes/no question - the program is clearly not shipped on 10.9 so let's focus on options to replicate it.

Comment: You said "I believe reg existed on 10.8 and lower" and the `reg` command last shipped with Mac OS X 10.7 and was not available in OS X 10.8 or later even though the man page still existed beyond Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell `reg` is only available in Lion (*/usr/bin/reg* and */usr/share/man/man1/reg.1*). I haven't been able to find it in any other system version in the 10.6 - 10.11 range.

Executing it in 10.10 works but I think some hardware data is missing. E.g my CPUs weren't recognized and I can't list any PCI device. Depending on the hardware your mileage will vary.

Comment: Can you imagine the internal discussions at Apple relating to shipping that tool? The manual page warns that you can **permanently damage your hardware** with it. I wonder why they even shipped it one time...

Answer (score 0):

10.11.3 there isn't even a man page. It appears to be gone, but I can't tell you what the replacement might be.

Comment: I apologize - I've removed the trivial part of the question. Feel free to edit / delete this as you see best fit.